# Editing questions without checking pending edits on the same question

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

So I am a bit confused by the system of editing questions. I understand that your edit will get instantly approved if you have more then 2k reputation, see the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Well for my particular case I edited the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172576/about-an-event-listener-inside-a-quiz-game) see my [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24188627). I noticed that my suggested edit got rejected by the 'Community' with the reason `This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.`. The reasoning makes totally sense to me, but I can't understand why someone can just go ahead and make an edit to the question e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58172576/revisions), without checking, if there are pending edits on this very question which are even 20 minutes ago.

Also IMO, the edits even change quite the same, even mine formats the code as real code lines.

Since I am not privileged enough to instantly edit questions I do not know, if you can even see pending edits on a question. Is this the case, can anything done about it?

Comment: When a suggested edit is already pending the "edit" link sends you to the edit review item. These clashes can probably only happen if both of you were making the edits at the same time.

Comment: Well yes, I already read about that, but IMO 20 minutes for editing a question this short seem very unlikely to me.

Comment: Okay, so the edit that clashed with yours was [done through the Help and Improvement queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/24188675). This is one of the toughest (and most time-consuming) queues out there, which probably explains why the edit took so long. Either that or the wires got crossed between the queues (I don't know if that is possible).

Comment: So if I would want to reformat the code or something else, I should go ahead and edit the question again, even if my last one got rejected by the system?

Comment: Well, since your edit doesn't seem to have been rejected in the usual way, it's probably safe to suggest it again. Although if (with the newer edits) the necessary changes are too superficial you should consider letting it go, as superficial edit suggestions are often a bit of a gamble in terms of review.

Comment: Yea I thought the same, such a shame. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: When the question is of low quality it may enter the "Help and Improvement" queue. The editor does not have the view if any pending edits are on, unless they expressly click on the link of the question to check. But it's not mandatory

Comment: At least IMO that is a pretty 'stupid' system.

Comment: @Twenty yeah, it's a *terrible* system for any sort of collaborative editing. Or just more than one person editing a post. Even if you have 2k rep, you get into situations where you edit a post and somebody overwrites your edit immediately after. It's even worse if several people are actively trying to edit one post (as opposed to randomly happening to) - say, a community wiki post that two or more people try to contribute to is a nightmare to manage.

Comment: On a related note.  Why can't someone who is has editing privileges immediately ok someone's edit.  I just ok'd someone's edit who did not have 2k rep and it said it needed one more vote.  If I am trusted to edit posts and have them applied immediately why am I not trusted to approve an edit that I might have made myself?